# Error when trying to convert from character to date in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to analyze a big data set. One of the columns is the starttime column and its original class is character.

I used this command:

```
data$starttime = strptime(data$starttime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S).
```

I'm getting this error message:

```
**Error in `[<-.data.table`(x, j = name, value = value) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'**
```

In addition: Warning message:

```
**In `[<-.data.table`(x, j = name, value = value) :
  Supplied 11 items to be assigned to 13118401 items of column 'startime' (recycled leaving remainder of 10 items).**
```

I also tried the `as.Date()` and `ymd_hms()` functions but they gave the same error. What exactly does this mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Would you please provide your data along with your code? You are likely to receive more help when you do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is in the nature of POSIXlt structure (being a list of 11 vectors). You can see this by looking at

```
names(unclass(strptime("2015-01-01", format = "%Y-%m-%d")))
# [1] "sec"    "min"    "hour"   "mday"   "mon"    "year"   "wday"   "yday"   "isdst"  "zone"  
# [11] "gmtoff"
```

Having a list in a data frame is not impossible but can cause unnecessary problems. Minimal example:

```
library(data.table)
df1 <- data.table(a = 1:2, time = sprintf("2015-01-%02d", 1:2))
df1$time <- strptime(df1$time, format = "%Y-%m-%d")

# Warning messages:
#   1: In `[<-.data.table`(x, j = name, value = value) :
#   Supplied 11 items to be assigned to 2 items of column 'time' (9 unused)
```

or

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- data_frame(a = 1:2, time = strptime(sprintf("2015-01-%02d", 1:2), format = "%Y-%m-%d"))
df1
# Warning message:
#   In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, is_list, value = list(time = c("<dbl[2]>",  :
#   replacement element 1 has 11 rows to replace 2 rows
```

I think using POSIX**c**t should solve at least one of your problems:

```
as.POSIXct(data$starttime, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```